# Issue while using BCP

Tags: sql-server-2014, bcp

I am trying to add data from a text file into SQL Server Database Table.

Sample Data from text file (I donot know how to attach file here so added image sample) :

I first used Import/Export option but somehow the data is getting inserted but showing NULL Values ? Any inputs why is it happening ?

Now,I am using bcp utility but I am facing issue while doing the task. Can I get some help on this.

```
Use Master
 GO

 EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
 RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
 GO

 EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
 RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
 GO


DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(512) = 'C:\Users\SQLBoy\Desktop\'

--Use BCP to copy files in character format from the target directly into the table. 
SET @sql = 'bcp [MyDB].[Schema].[Destinationtable] in ' + @path + 'new1.txt -c -T'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

I am getting error.

> Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run
>   the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> Configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed from 1 to 1. Run the
>   RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> Msg 214, Level 16, State 201, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 12
>
> Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'.

I used `VARCHAR(1000)` and I am getting below issue :

output

> NULL
>
> Starting copy...
>
> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF
>   encountered in BCP data-file
>
> NULL
>
> 0 rows copied.
>
> Network packet size (bytes): 4096
>
> Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1
>
> ```
>  NULL
> ```

Comment: You can't use `VARCHAR(MAX)` with `xp_cmdshell`. Have you tried with finite number? Error message is misleading though.

Comment: Hi @JSapkota,thanks for the response and I just updated my question.

Comment: Could you use DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)  Because the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000.

Comment: @JSapkota,I just updated my question.Can you please see.Thanks.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan,thanks for the response.I used 8000 but still same issue.

Comment: @SQLBoy,make sure that there are no hidden control characters or unintentional space anywhere in the input file. And you have permission of that folder from where you are importing the data.

Comment: Remove that headers(Dataset, column1, column2 etc.) from the data file and try again. Make sure that `destinationtable` has enough columns to hold these records. Your code is working fine for me to import my sample data file. So the problem is in your data file or in your destination table.

Comment: Thanks @JSapkota,I am able to insert data from .txt file. Issue is the column headers in my SQL Server Table and .txt file are not same.Once I made then match I am able to import the data. Thanks for your response and help.

Comment: Don't use reconfigure with override, that's a great way to break SQL. Just use reconfigure.